# Does max-max optimization ordering matter?

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

It might be a trivial question. Consider a continuous and differentiable function (highly non-convex) $f:X \times Y \to ℝ$.
Would this always be true that

$$\max_{ \in } \max_{ \in } f(x,y)= \max_{\in} \max_{ \in } f(x,y)= \max_{x,y \in X \times Y} f(x,y)$$

Note that both are max operators. If that doesn't always hold, then what are the conditions under which these equalities hold?

I see a similar question in [Maximize function of two variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189307/maximize-function-of-two-variables), but I don't think I got what I wanted out of this page! I need a little more clues.

Could you tell me what the definition of $^∗ = \text{argmax}_{y} f(x,y)$ is? I think that's where I get confused. If it was $x^* = \text{argmax}_{x} f(x)$ (the outer optimization), then the definition would have been something like $f(x^*) > f(x)$ for all $x$ in the feasible set. What would be the analogous definition here?

Answer (score 1):

This is identical. If one considers WLOG that

$$\underbrace{\max_{ \in } \max_{ \in } f(x,y)}_{f(x_0,y_0)} < \underbrace{\max_{\in} \max_{ \in } f(x,y)}_{f(x_1,y_1)}$$

then obviously $[x_0,y_0] \neq [x_1,y_1]$ and

$f(x_1,y_1) \le \max_{ \in } f(x,y_1) \le \max_{ \in } [\max_{ \in } f(x,y)]=f(x_0,y_0)\,\mathbf{<}\,f(x_1,y_1)$

which is contradictory. Therefore equality is the only possibility.

Comment: ?? I see! But I am not convinced yet. Could you be kind enough to tell me what the definition of $y^* = \argmax_{y} f(x,y)$ is? I think that's where I get confused. If it was a x^* = \argmax_{x} f(x) (the outer optimization), then the definition would have been something like f(x^*) > f(x) for all x in the feasible set. What would be the analogous definition here?

Comment: The definition of $ \text{argmax}_{y} f(x,y)$ is standard  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max), where $x$ is taken as parameter. It is however a set which can contain more than one element in general. Regarding the result, look also to this article www.zazen.cz/media/av/max-max-opt.pdf to Eq. (7) or to this book www.zazen.cz/media/av/Introduction_to_the_Theory_of_Games_by_McKinsey_page18_Exercice11.pdf to page 18, Exercise 11 (this book is referenced in that article).

Comment: New question relevant to this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4360002/max-x-max-yfx-y-max-x-yfx-y-then-arg-max-x-arg-max-yfx-y

Comment: Very useful link. Thank you.