When is $\max_a \max_b =\max_b \max_a $
Lets consider a real valued and continuous function $f$ which takes 2 objects as input. If $f$ is symmetric: $f(a,b) = f(b,a)$ then I can obviously say:
$$\max\limits_{a\,\in A} \max\limits_{b\, \in B} f(a,b) = \max\limits_{b\, \in B} \max\limits_{a\,\in A}  f(a,b).$$
Now assume that $A,B$ are compact sets and $f$ is not necessarily symmetric. What conditions have to be satisfied by $f$ to make the same statement?

Have you tried any examples?

Sufficient ( though not necessary ) Criteria : When the Maxima occurs in $A \cap B$ , then we can make that Statement.

Did you find any counterexamples? (Those might prove very useful for determining the conditions of the equality case)

In my specific case I was thinking of hermitian matrices and a quantum channel F as a function $A={X: |X|{\text{tr}} \leq 1 }$ and $B={X: |X|{\infty} \leq 1 }$ and $f(X,Y) = |tr(X^\dagger \mathcal{F}(Y))|$. I was wondering when I can vs cannot do the swap.

@AnneBauval yes in my cases I can assume that A and B have metrics (although not the same)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4353030/does-max-max-optimization-ordering-matter Seems related

@Anne Bauval great minds and all that ;(

Sorry, I fixed the post now. I think the post linked by Steen82 is related no? So my question is a duplicate. Thanks for pointing me to the answer.

The answer in the linked post is really unclear to me (moreover, the hypothesis are not the same). Here is a much more elegant and convincing proof.

v.tralala Why can you "obviously say $\max\limits_{a,\in A} \max\limits_{b, \in B} f(a,b) = \max\limits_{b, \in B} \max\limits_{a,\in A}  f(a,b)$" if $f$ is symmetric?

Edited Question with Exchanging $a \leftrightarrow b$ & $A \leftrightarrow B$ has drastically changed the Question into something almost obviously true. Initial Question was a lot more non-trivial !

The initial question was trivially mistaken, and the new one, not so obvious, was worth a proof.
